# Trying to convert Tabulator into a functional component with React - Can't reference DOM Node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

So after a lot of trial and error with the React-Tabulator library (out of date), I have decided to implement Tabulator by utilizing the vanilla JS implementation shown here: https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/frameworks#react

I've converted this over to a functional component and it appears on screen as expected, however I can not access the DOM node in order to utilize specific functions like selectRow, getData, etc.

I know this has to do with refs and so forth but I've exhausted all the avenues I can think of to achieve what I need. Ideally I want to be able to utilize a select dropdown to choose something, and depending on what I choose, it will select a certain number of rows based off their row ID. I know how to get this to function but in order to do so I just need help accessing the DOM node of the table. It currently just returns undefined or null.

Below is the functional component I built:
`

```
import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from "tabulator-tables";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css";
import "tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator_semanticui.min.css";

const Table = ({ data, columns, options }) => {
    const ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        new Tabulator(ref.current, {
            data: data,
            columns: columns,
            ...options,
        });
    }, [columns, data, options]);

    return <div ref={ref} className="celled compact" />;
};

export default Table;
```

`

`

```
<Table data={sources.data.source_data} columns={sourceColumns} options={{layout: "fitColumns"}} />
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue with React-Tabulator (still looking for solution). With vanilla JS, did ping-pong trick:

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-mountain-enliwk?file=/src/App.js

I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the solution. I however am looking for a way to make a reusable Table component that I can then reference outside of the component to manipulate the DOM. All the examples I see just have it as a one page component where they are doing it all, but nothing points to being able to reference the table in a parent component.

Comment: Please try to use code snippets and parts of code that you think is relevant instead of sending the user to another link. Use it as a supporting link but show the code in the answer to be more specific.